# How do I print the contents of a list that is a key inside a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'__module__': 'pyof.v0x04.controller2switch.common',
 '__doc__': 'Bucket for use in groups.',
 'length': UBInt16(None),
 'weight': UBInt16(None),
 'watch_port': UBInt32(None),
 'watch_group': UBInt32(None),
 'pad': Pad(4),
 'actions': [],
 '__init__': <function Bucket.__init__ at 0x7fbaa2a99ea0>,
 'unpack': <function Bucket.unpack at 0x7fbaa2a99f28>,
 'get_size': <function Bucket.get_size at 0x7fbaa2aa8048>}
```

And I'm interested in printing the content of the key `'actions'` which has a list inside. I've tried `for` loops, but I'm clearly doing something wrong because I'm not getting anything to print.

Comment: for each_item in your_dictionary['actions']:
    # process each_item

Comment: A list is not hashable and can not be a key in a dictionary. In your snippet `[]` is a *value*.

Comment: In your snippet `[]` is the ***value*** associated with the dictionary ***key*** `'actions'`. Please [edit] your question and add the code of your attempt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your idea was actually correct if you have done something like this:

```py
for i in dict["actions"]:
  print( i )
```

But in your question the actions key is represented as `[]`, that means, it is empty

Answer (score 0):

`print(dictionary_name["actions"])` will print the content referenced by the key `actions`, this will work for every single key in a dictionary. You can access elements inside a dictionary simply by specifying the key (like the list index notation, but with... keys)

Comment: u don't need to loop through every single key XD